# Return JSON for exception with octoberCMS

Tags: php, error-handling, octobercms

I have some custom routes

```
Route::get('/files/', [
            'as' => 'read',
            'uses' => 'Myname\MyPlugin\Http\Controllers\FilesController@read'
        ]);
```

Somewhere in my class I have a function to validate a path

```
private function getPath()
{
    $path = Input::get('path');

    if (!$path)
    {
    throw new MyException('parameter is missing. path required', 400);
    }

    return base_path().'/'.$path;
}
```

I have set a custom error handler with a JSOM but it's the error handler of OctoberCMS that render the error in HTML format.

Do you know a way to replace default error handler of OctoberCMS by a custom one ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the anwser in the documentation : https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log#exception-handling

October provide App:error to manage Exception in your plugin.

```
App::error(function(MyException $exception) {
//do what you want here
}
```

Don't forger to create a custom Exception for your plugin. If you use the generic **Exception**, you'll catch all the Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an alternative solution here for a custom error handler because of this questions's visibility on Google.

I had problems using `App:error` due to this issue on Github: https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3416

---

Rather than using October's `App::error` for a custom error handling, try the following:

1. Create a custom error handler that inherit's from October's error handler. For example, create the following class in `plugins/{AUTHOR}/{PLUGIN}/classes/CustomHandler.php` (assuming you are developing a plugin for OctoberCMS). Override the `render` method of the handler.

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace {AUTHOR}\{PLUGIN}\Classes; //<-- CHANGE ME OBVIOUSLY FOR YOUR PLUGIN

   use October\Rain\Foundation\Exception\Handler;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
   use Exception;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException; // As an example exception you want to handle ...

   /* Custom error handler which replaces the default error handler for OctoberCMS. */
   class CustomHandler extends Handler
   {
       /**
       * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @param  \Exception  $exception
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
       public function render($request, Exception $exception)
       {
           /* Custom JSON response for ModelNotFoundException exceptions. */
           if($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException){
               return Response::json(['error' => 'A record was not found for the resource that was requested.'], 404);
           }

           /* The rest of this code is just the 'default' code from OctoberCMS' error handler. */
           /* The only change is the code above this comment where I handle a specific exception in a unique way.*/
           /* i.e. I decided to return JSON for the error rather than an HTML error page (in debug mode). */
           if (!class_exists('Event')) {
               return parent::render($request, $exception);
           }

           $statusCode = $this->getStatusCode($exception);
           $response = $this->callCustomHandlers($exception);

           if (!is_null($response)) {
               return Response::make($response, $statusCode);
           }

           if ($event = Event::fire('exception.beforeRender', [$exception, $statusCode, $request], true)) {
               return Response::make($event, $statusCode);
           }

           return parent::render($request, $exception);
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Then, in your plugin registration file `Plugin.php`, add a `boot` method with the following code:

   ```
   <?php namespace {AUTHOR}\{PLUGIN};

   use System\Classes\PluginBase;
   use {AUTHOR}\{PLUGIN}\Classes\CustomHandler; //<-- IMPORTANT
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;  //<-- IMPORTANT

   class Plugin extends PluginBase
   {
      /**
      * @var array Plugin dependencies
      */
      public $require = [];


      public function registerComponents()
      {
      }

      public function registerSettings()
      {
      }

      public function boot(){


          /* Replace the default error handler of OctoberCMS to return JSON format responses instead. */
          /* Also, this is used in order to control the responses for certain types of errors/exceptions. */
          /* We are going about it this way because App::error (as mentioned in the documentation for OctoberCMS), */
          /* was not returning the response properly presumably because of a bug. Argh... */
          $this->app->bind(
              ExceptionHandler::class,
              CustomHandler::class
          );


      }


   }
   ```

Since, the new `CustomHandler.php` was added to the `classes` directory, the new class should already be picked up. No need for `composer dump-autoload -o` or changes to the `composer.json`.

That is it. When the `ModelNotFoundException` occurs, the response given to the web browser will be JSON that you wrote (from the custom error handler we created).

Relevant links:

- https://blog.sarav.co/registering-custom-exception-handler-laravel-5/
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding
- https://octobercms.com/forum/post/is-it-posible-to-bring-back-the-app-directory-for-native-laravel